# Java String Remove one letter at a time

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm trying to remove one letter at a time from a word. For example, if the word it math, I want to try: ath, mth, mah 
Right now I have:

```
  for (int i = 1; i < word.length() ; i++){
         String removed = word.substring(0, i -1) 
             + word.substring(i -1 , word.length());

  //do something with the word
}
```

This doesn't work because I get the error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please show the full stack trace and mark the line where the error occurs.

Comment: It's a very large program and this is only one component of it, but the stack trace leads to this line.

Comment: luckily, the deepest calls are at the top of the trace. Please post the trace and highlight the line in your source code, that throws this exception.

Comment: Oh I actually realize the source of the error is not this line. Thanks!!!
There was an error here, but I must have fixed it. It's now something else.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. The exception in a comment is unreadable. And again: please mark the line where the exception occurs.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with my program, it wasn't this. I'm going to delete this post. Thank you so much for trying to help!

Comment: Whatever you do in here, consider using `StringBuilder` since String operations are resource expensive - you basically create a new object each time. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
   String removed = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < word.length() ; i++){
            String removed = word.substring(0, i - 1) 
                + word.substring(i , word.length());

            System.out.println(removed);
         //do something with the word
        }
```

Actually you need to start from `i` not `i - 1` in getting the 2nd part of the final word. For example you can see this is needed and working `word.substring(i , word.length());`

It is not throwing the exception though.

Comment: It isn't an answer then, isn't it?

Comment: He is asking how to do this one letter removal with the code snippet provided so here i am giving solution to one issue that is the mistake in the code but yes that other issue of exception is not reproducible for me.

Comment: Yeah. Because the question was incomplete. Because a stack trace was missing. That is why we ask for clarification in the comments. As you may be aware, OP stated that the "problem" stemmed from a totally different line in hers/his code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
public class LetterRemover {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    String hello = "hello";

    for (int i = 1; i < hello.length(); ++i) {
      if(i == 1) {
        System.out.println(hello.substring(i));
      } else {
        System.out.println(hello.substring(0, i-1) + hello.substring(i));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int wordLength = word.length();
for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    String removed = word.substring(0, i )
            + word.substring(i + 1, wordLength);
    System.out.println(removed);
    //do something with the word
}
```

You need to remove 1 char every time so u should make it like two words and concatenate each to other.

1. The first word starts with no char (0 to 0) and the second word (1 to word length). So now you skip first char.
2. You make the first word (0 to 1) and the second word (2 to word length). So now you skip second char etc.

Comment: How is this different and why does this work? Along with your answer, please explain what you have changed.

Comment: you need to remove 1 char every time so u should make it like two word and concatenate each to other .step 1: first word start with no char (0 to 0) and second word (1 to word length). so now u skip first char .step 2: u make first word (0 to 1) and second word (2 to word length). so now u skip second char .etc